# How to change Theme of an activity in Android

Tags: android

I am new to android i have a button when I click on that button its show a popup menu.
It have two item day and night. 
When I press night button the entire activity theme change to black, text color white and i press day button its change to white,text color black.
I have a code but its change only the popup menus theam.
How can i change my activity theam .

My code:

```
first class

btn_mode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_content_mode);
        btn_mode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("bfr calling popup class");
                PopupMenu_Mode popup_mode=new PopupMenu_Mode(context, btn_mode);
                popup_mode. Popup_Menu();
                //call_popupMode();

            }
        });



second class

public class PopupMenu_Mode extends Activity {
    PopupMenu popup_Mode;
    Context context;
    Button b;
    Activity activity;

    public PopupMenu_Mode(Context context, Button btn_mode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.b = btn_mode;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Popup_Menu() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        System.out.println("inside popup mode class");
        popup_Mode = new PopupMenu(context, b);
        popup_Mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mode, popup_Mode.getMenu());
        System.out.println("show popup mode ");
        popup_Mode.show();
        popup_Mode.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.day:

                        context.setTheme(R.style.AppThemeLight);
                        // l.setBackgroundColor(R.style.AppThemeDark);
                        break;
                    case R.id.night:
                        context.setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark);
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nothing",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                return false;

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppThemeLight" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Instead of theme , Set the black/white color on Parent Layout .

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme of Activity in onCreate():

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);
```

You have to set theme before calling 'onCreate()' and 'setContentView()' method.

Comment: But i want to change the color ,when i press the day button only.

Comment: You need to do the same we discussed. Anyhow Can you please refer the sample at  https://sites.google.com/site/ramkiranworks/customization/Themes.zip?attredirects=0&d=1

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme programmatically as Subramanian said. But refer to this link https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4394 as it was discussed earlier.

You must call setTheme method before `super.onCreate()` & `setContentView()` method.

Comment: Its work for me..but i want to change the theme in a button click.how can i do this..